# Understanding the Threshold Process in Harris Corner and Edge Detector

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, classification, feature-extraction, corners

I have read the paper [Chris Harris , Mike Stephens - A Combined Corner and Edge Detector](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.231.1604) about the **Harris Corner and Edge Detector**, but I didn't understand the point that after low and high threshold they have got 5 regions, specially the point where he has got 2 corner classes, can you please explain that to me with image so I can get that point?

- here is the part of the paper which I didn't understand:

> - By applying low and high thresholds, edge hysteresis can be carried out, and this can enhance the continuity of edges.
>
> - These classifications thus result in a **5-level image** comprising:

> > 1. Background.
> > 2. **Two corner classes**.
> > 3. Two edge classes.

**Thanks in advance**

[image: image after high and low threshold]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing the low and high thresholds to the eigenvalues, there will be 2 types of corners:

1. weak corners which are close to the low thresholding value.
2. strong corners which are above the high thresholding value.

[image: Harris Corner]